# USB Kingston pendrive recognized by lsusb but is not assigned a /dev/sd* path

Tags: usb-drive

I installed Arch Linux on a USB 2.0 Kingston 16GB DTSE9 pendrive. At some point the system froze and required a cold reboot. After that the pendrive is not recognized or mounted anymore both on Windows and Linux, though it is listed for a few moments after plugging in by lsusb. However it's not shown by fdisk. The device is not assigned a /dev/sd* that I can mount.

Is there anything I can do to mount and format this pendrive?

Here are the outputs.

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 1038:136f Ideazon, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13fe:3400 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
->>> Bus 002 Device 112: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg

```
[ 7839.424124] usb 2-1.1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
[ 7839.424128] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 7839.424132] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 1C6F654E4910AD7169541303
[ 7839.424947] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 7839.425455] scsi18 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[ 7861.892030] usb 2-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 44 using ehci-pci
[ 7876.981274] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 7892.174618] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 7892.350833] usb 2-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 44 using ehci-pci
[ 7907.439953] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 7922.633339] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 7922.809520] usb 2-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 44 using ehci-pci
[ 7933.229324] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 44, error -110
[ 7933.301574] usb 2-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 44 using ehci-pci
[ 7943.721328] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 44, error -110
[ 7943.721636] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 44
[ 7943.793497] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 45 using ehci-pci
[ 7958.882755] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 7974.076122] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 7974.252309] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 46 using ehci-pci
[ 7989.341481] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 8004.534825] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 8004.711011] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 47 using ehci-pci
[ 8015.130866] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 47, error -110
[ 8015.203075] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 48 using ehci-pci
[ 8025.622811] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 48, error -110
[ 8025.622911] usb 2-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 8138.676017] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 49 using ehci-pci
[ 8138.768885] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1665
[ 8138.768888] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Installed Arch linux on the pendrive or used it to install Arch linux on hard drive ?

You may try again after running `sudo partprobe` on Linux.

There is a very good chance of killing your USB drive, during a reboot while some data is still writing or reading on the drive. If possible always do a `sync` before removing any pendrive or harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Kingston DTSE9 pendrives are based on a Phison PS2251-68 controller chip that can lose or corrupt its internal firmware in some situations. This might be what has happened here.

If you Google for "Phison PS2251-68 recovery tools", you will find various third-party sites offering tools for re-flashing the pendrive firmware. If you find something you can trust (after a good check for malware, of course), it might be possible to restore your pendrive... but you will need a Windows system to run the firmware tools.

Alternatively, it seems Kingston has a five-year warranty policy on DTSE9, so if you bought it less than five years ago, you might get it replaced by contacting either the vendor or Kingston directly.

Answer (score 0):

You might have messed the USB drive, since `dmesg` is showing errors trying to read the device descriptor... so there is a chance of descriptor corruption.

But as far as I see, the system recognizes your drive at the end.

If you have `udev` in your Linux, try to see if the device is under `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-*manufacturer_serialnumber*`. 
In your case try with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_1C6F654E4910AD7169541303` to see which exact dev-node was assigned, if any.