# USB drive is not recognized in all Linux

Tags: linux, usb, flash

I have a Smartbuy 16Gb USB 2.0 flash drive (whith new memory controler) that is not recognized in any Linux system,
but on Windows it recognized and worked fine.

When I connect it to the PC on Linux system, nothing happens.
In dmesg appears this lines:

```
[ 2454.940289] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 2455.051632] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=4300
[ 2455.051636] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2455.051639] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB DISK 2.0
[ 2455.051641] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer:         
[ 2455.051643] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 9000883E242B3934
[ 2455.051971] usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2455.052148] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[ 2456.640210] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 2456.844280] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 2457.048278] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 2457.252279] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
```

In lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 13fe:4300 Kingston Technology Company Inc.
```

fdisk -l and parted -l not return recognizing the USB device or partitions.

This solution: https://superuser.com/a/1107319
and reformat on Windows to fat32, didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port such as one that's using USB 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I was tried on different ports, 2.0 and 3.0. I connect to dicrect ports from  back-side panel of the system motherboard. Other USB flash drives, and devices working fine.

Comment: The four resets are looking suspicious, what you should see instead are an attempt to read the partition table, and at least an assignment to `/dev/sdX` if no partition table is found.  Any trouble with other USB devices under Linux? If you have a powered USB hub, can you connect it, and connect the flash drive to the hub? What kernel are you using, and can you upgrade to a newer kernel (to rule out driver trouble)?

Comment: 1. Assignment to /dev/sdX not happening. This is realy last strings of dmesg after plug USB drive.
2. I have no trouble with any other USB devices under all systems.

3.
> If you have a powered USB hub, can you connect it, and connect the flash drive to the hub?
Now I don't have USB hub, but this is a very strange advice.
I have no problems with system power.
In most cases, it is advised not to use USB hub if happen any problems.

Comment: 4. Current kernel of my system Kubuntu 18.04 is 4.15.0-46-generic.
Also I tried in systems from Ubuntu 12.04 to 19.04, and Fedora 29.
But USB drive was not work, and output of dmesg was same.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213218/usb-kingston-pendrive-recognized-by-lsusb-but-is-not-assigned-a-dev-sd-path

Answer (score 1):

- To access the USB drive first you need to mount it.
- After you plug in your USB device to your USB port, Linux system adds
  a new block device into /dev/.
- Use command `sudo fdisk -l`
- This command will list all the detected devices, check out your USB by checking the storage of the list shown.
- Note the block name of the USB drive (something similar - /dev/sdc, can change depends on your system).
- mount it using `mount /dev/sdc /mount/point/`

Comment: I'm not new Linux user. Of course I know those things that you wrote. I can't mount it because block device of flash drive is missing in the system.

Comment: @Wnsemn-you didn't say the block device was missing

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same problem Several times.
This happens after I install a new version of Linux kernel but did not reboot.
so the kernel you are running and the kernel you installed is not matched.

You can check this by using `uname -a` and `ls /usr/lib/modules`.

So the solution is simply **`reboot`** your system.

Comment: For me this is the correct answer: A reboot after a new kernel installation. Especially important on Arch Linux because they often upgrade the kernel.