# USB Stick Device not detected as a disk on Linux, but in Windows it works

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-drive

I have a issue with my usb stick on linux: it is detected in `lsusb` but not as a disk: there is no entry in `fdisk -l`, programs like Gparted or Gnome-Disk don't recognize it either
This means it is not the commom problem that I could solve with `mount`

When I run `lsusb` the entry for this device is:

`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 13fe:4300 Kingston Technology Company Inc.`

When I run `dmesg | grep -i usb`

```
[  117.577013] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  117.850868] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=4300
[  117.850871] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  117.850874] usb 2-3: Product: USB DISK 2.0
[  117.850876] usb 2-3: Manufacturer:         
[  117.850878] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 2700010AB2615E49
[  118.503935] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  118.504012] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: Quirks match for vid 13fe pid 4300: 800000
[  118.504032] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[  118.504118] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  118.530812] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  140.948129] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
```

When I run `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/`, this device is showed this way:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13fe ProdID=4300 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=        
S:  Product=USB DISK 2.0
S:  SerialNumber=2700010AB2615E49
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
```

What I found interesting the device is recognized as usb-storage and as UsB Disk

**Notes**

- As I pointed above, Gparted doesn't recognizes the device
- There is no entry of this device in `fdisk -l`
- This is not a problem solved with `mount`
- Other Usb Sticks devices works fine
- This device works fine on Windows
- The problem occurred in Ubuntu and Mageia

**EDIT**

Partially worked:

- I started VBox and trying to connect the usb stick in the guest (recognized as usb but not as a disk in linux guest)
- After disconnect from VM the host Ubuntu could detect and mount automatically the usb

If I unplug the usb device and try to plug it again, it doesn't recognizes it anymore

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506154/usb-drive-is-not-recognized-in-all-linux